# Exclude git versioning for json type files in Visual Studio Code

Tags: json, gitignore

I cannot exclude my sites generated json data files from showing up in git changes. I have a directory named `json` with several `.json` files in it. I do not want to commit any files in this directory.

I have added the folder to .gitignore as `json/*` but that's not working, nor is the literal json file name, such as `json/somefile.json`.

I have also tried to add a files.exclude to Visual Studio Code Workspace Settings which is also not working.

```
{
    "editor.fontSize": 12,
    "editor.mouseWheelScrollSensitivity": 2,
    "editor.mouseWheelZoom": true,
    "window.zoomLevel": 0.1,
    "git.ignoreLimitWarning": true,
    "files.exclude": {
        "**/json": true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you did not previously add those files to your Git index.

Switch to command line and type:

```
cd /path/to/my/repo
git rm --cached -r -- json/
echo json/>>.gitignore
git status
```

Check if those files are still listed in your git status then.

Once that is done, you can switch back to VSCode.